# Extending artifactory's pypi repos with plugins

Tags: artifactory, pypi

I am trying to migrate a legacy system to use artifactory. However I have two blockers:

1. the old scripts require PyPixmlrpc, which artifactory doesn't support

   they also make use of upload_docs, not supported by artifactory's pypi implementation either

   a smaller issue, the old scripts call register and they expect 200 instead of 204 http status code.

Would it be possible for me to write a plugin to implement this?

Looking at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins I couldn't find a callback for when `POST /api/pypi/<index-name>` is requested.

If I can make

1. work for the methods we actually use,

   to just pretend it deployed docs and

   to respond with the correct status code

I will be happy enough.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, there is no plugin hook for the Pypi API endpoints. It would be possible to use the `altResponse` endpoint to customize artifact downloads, but then you would be restricted to `GET` requests with no request body, which is also not a good option for you.

I think the most viable approach would be to define a custom [`executions`](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions) endpoint. With this, you can specify the acceptable method, read the body, and set your own response code and body. The main shortcoming with this is that you can't customize the path (it's always `/api/plugins/execute/[execution_name]`), but this can be worked around.

Execution endpoints can take params in the following form:

`/api/plugins/execute/[execution_name]?params=[param_name]=[param_val]`

Say your plugin takes a param `path`, which represents the API path your old scripts are going to call. Then you can set your base URL to `/api/plugins/execute/[execution_name]?params=path=/`, so that the API path is appended to the param. Alternatively, you can use nginx or another reverse proxy to rewrite the original API path to this form.

(Since you'll be using XML-RPC, I don't suppose you'll need to worry about any of this path stuff, but I'm including it anyway for completeness.)

Some issues with this approach:

- Execution endpoints only allow `String` responses, so sending binary data in the response body might be finnicky. However, no such limitation exists with the request body.
- If you need more than one request method, you'll need more than one execution endpoint. This means you'll need to use a reverse proxy to rewrite each method to a separate endpoint. Again, since XML-RPC just uses `POST`, this probably won't be an issue for you.
- Execution endpoints can't customize response headers. Therefore, if your scripts expect a particular `Content-Type` or other header, you'll need to use a reverse proxy to insert it into the response.

Comment: This would basically require me to reimplement pypi using the executions endpoit, wouldn't it? Both upload_docs and the normal upload use the same endpoint, but with different values for some form field. Either that or my reverse proxy will have to parse form data. I guess the xmlrpc bit would be a bit more doable, though. However, it seems like I'd be able to reuse very little code from artifactory's pypi implementation. Which is a shame.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida You could try directing what you can to the Artifactory implementation by calling local REST endpoints from inside the plugin. Other than that, yes, you'd need to implement a lot of it yourself. There doesn't seem to be any way around this, whatever the approach.